# Can we have the `pine` language code associated with specific tags in order to have it correctly highlighted in questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request

TradingView would like to implement highlighting for [Pine Script™](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Introduction.html) code, which is typically used in the `[pine-script]`, `[pine-script-v4]` and `[pine-script-v5]` tags.

It is mentioned in section 2b of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) that for highlighting purposes, a language code can be associated with a tag through a feature request. Our understanding is that if `highlight.js` contains proper support for the language, SO will use it to highlight code in the tags associated with that language code.

1. Do language codes associated with a tag still exist for highlighting purposes?
2. If so, how do we go about getting our language code associated with the tags?
3. If not, what should we do to obtain proper highlighting of Pine code in the three tags we mentioned?

Comment: The very same FAQ you link to, [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), has it very clear as you noted: *If [a] tag doesn't have a highlighting language specified when it should, create a [tag:feature-request] on **your site's per-site meta** to request it. (Only moderators can change the highlighting language for a tag.)*

Comment: Each site has its own per-site meta to discuss things about that site. This site, Meta Stack Exchange, is the global meta site for issues affecting the entire network or a group of sites, so an exact request for it would be off-topic here. You can access this per-site meta by first going to the site in question, clicking the help icon on the top right, then clicking "Meta".

Comment: Aha. Thx. Hadn't understood the site-specific Meta subtlety. Will do. Apologies for posting here.

Comment: Which site had you wanted to get this enabled on?

Comment: stackoverflow.com, so we are planning to ask a `[feature-request]` here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ hoping that's the correct way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what to do.