# Can you please add Pine to the list of "Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange"?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

As a follow-up to [this question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388320/can-we-have-the-pine-language-code-associated-with-specific-tags-in-order-to-h) and [this one on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424163/could-you-please-add-the-pine-language-code-to-three-tags?noredirect=1#comment953964_424163), I would like to know if it is possible to add Pine to the list of "Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange" appearing on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

From mod comments on my MSO question, it appears that before they can associate the `pine` language code to the `[pine-script]`, `[pine-script-v4]` and `[pine-script-v5]` MSO tags, the language must be supported by SE explicitly even if it's supported by Highlight.js.

Pine is already supported in Highlight.js, but is not in Stack Exchange's installation.

Per the above first link's duplicate target:

> Additionally, several languages that are indicated as supported in highlight.js's documentation may also not be supported by Stack Exchange version of highlight.js, as they are in separate modules which may not be deployed on Stack Exchange.

Pine happens to be one such language.

Comment: Sorry that makes zero sense. Should first have it, then write that it's there. That's list of codes that are **available** so before it's available, that would confusing and wrong.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard How does this not make sense? The first link's duplicate target (the syntax highlighting FAQ) states that only some of Highlight.js's languages are supported on the SE network, and that one should make a request here to have it supported before the hint can be added to tags on specific sites - see the section *Requesting that Stack Exchange support a new language which is* already supported by highlight.js.

Comment: Before your edit it said "it must be present in the list of supported languages on SE" (i.e. I get it as "should edit the list and add it) and that's what making zero sense, maybe I should have been more explicit in the comment.

Comment: Any hope we can get support for Pine in Stack Exchange's installation?